# Avoiding loops in matching records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to reduce a loop in SQL Server, and I'm kind of stumped.  I need to pair buys and sells by a given criteria.  For that criteria, a group of buys can match with a group of sells.  Not every buy can match with every sell (and vice versa), but a single buy can match with more than one sell (and vice versa).  I can easily get a temp table of all possible matches, but the hard part is pairing off a single buy to a single sell only only using each once.

Though looping in some way seems inevitable, I'd rather not use a cursor, due to the volume of records.  I'd like to go by one set of criteria at a time (e.g. grab the first pair for each item).  I'm trying to use a temp table #T of possible matches, narrow them down to pairs, and repeat.  At the very least, I loop 100 times instead of a million.

Here's a snippet of temp table #T:

```
MatchID    BuyID    SellID
      1       91        59
      2       91        60
      3       97        59
      4       97        60
```

For the above, I can keep either MatchIDs 1 and 4 or 2 and 3.  I had tried to use this algorithm to narrow it down:

1. Delete a record with a greater MatchID but same BuyID
2. Delete a record with a greater MatchID but same SellID

If I do this, step (1) deletes records 2 and 4, while step (2) deletes record 3.  I am able to reorder the records in SQL so the pairs have different MatchIDs, but I'm bound to what I can do in SQL Server.  I have tried ordering the matches in different ways, but nothing gives me something I can apply an algorithm to.

Has anyone else had a problem like this?

Comment: what should be matched in this case: (1,2,3),(2,2,4),(3,3,5)?

Comment: Is this as complex as the data really gets? Or is it possible that there are 5 `BuyID` rows for BuyID = 98, and only 3 `BuyID` rows for BuyID = 99? You say that they won't all match each other so could it be that `BuyID` of 98 also only matches `SellID` values of 59 and 60? In this case 59 and 60 have already been used for BuyID values of 91 and 97, so what to do?

Comment: The data does in fact get more complicated, but I didn't want the question to get too confusing.  Consider it a given that BuyID 91 can be matched to SellID 59 or 60, and the same for BuyID 97.  However, I can only match one BuyID at a time, so I need to throw away matches that are duplicates, without making too many passes in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough one! I think this works.

```
CREATE TABLE #t (MatchID INT, BuyID INT, SellID INT)
INSERT  #t
SELECT 1, 91, 59 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 91, 60 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 97, 59 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 97, 60


DELETE
  #t
WHERE
  MatchID IN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.MatchID
  FROM
    (
     SELECT
      MatchID,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SellID ORDER BY SellID) AS Row
     FROM
      #t
    ) AS t1
    CROSS JOIN 
    (
      SELECT
        MatchID,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BuyID ORDER BY BuyID) AS Row
      FROM
        #t
     ) AS t2
  WHERE
    t1.Row <> 1 AND
    t2.Row <> 1
)

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window Function` to find the `greater MatchID` for `SellId` and `BuyID`. Then use `CTE` to delete the records

```
CREATE TABLE #test
  (
     MatchID INT,
     BuyID   INT,
     SellID  INT
  )

INSERT #test
VALUES ( 1,91,59),
       ( 2,91,60),
       ( 3,97,59),
       ( 4,97,60);

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY buyid ORDER BY matchid DESC)B_rn,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY sellid ORDER BY matchid DESC)S_rn,
                *
         FROM   #test)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  1 IN ( b_rn, s_rn )
```